# The differences between Sencha Touch 1 and 2, especially regarding Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently trying to evaluate an old mobile application, and whether it is worth it to migrate it to Sencha 2, or if it even is Sencha 1, like I think it is.  So here are my questions:

1. How can I determine it is Sencha 1.X?  I suspect that it is, but I have not been able to find any version numbers.  I noticed some things like Model declarations seem to be consistent with some documentation I found regarding Sencha 1.X, but other aspects are not.  (For example, in model files, it has `Ext.regModel('app.models.Model', {fields: [] });` rather than the Sencha 2 style `Ext.define('app.models.Model', {extend: 'Ext.data.Model'});`, but the controllers don't match the Sencha 1 pattern, as shown here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/guide/upgrade_1_to_2 .)
2. The application I'm evaluating is definitely using Phonegap 1.3.  I'm wondering when PhoneGap is required for 1 and for 2, and when it is not required.  It seems to me that I've read somewhere that Sencha Touch 1 may need Phonegap more often than 2.
3. If there are any other notable differences between Sencha Touch 1 and 2. Through my research, I've found a little about this already saying the following:

   -Sencha Touch 1 does not have good documentation (part of the reason for my asking these questions)

   -Sencha Touch 2 has better performance

   -Sencha Touch 2 has better MVC design patterns

Answer (score 0):

1. run

   ```
   Ext.version
   ```
2. Please there is no such question, because to have the latest support for all devices you are better off with a platform being used 1 Million times instead of Sencha Touch (which actually in 2 supports commands like "sencha cordova init".
   There might be even a reason for this.
3. Again: Please there is no such question. If you need a more stable version with current support, or even think about sending questions about Sencha 1 to stackoverflow, you might be alone.
   The last time I coded Sencha 1 was 3 years ago, when I pushed an app from Sencha1 to Sencha2.

After working on Sencha 2 for years now, I cannot even remember how we could ever have done anything inside Sencha 1. Nowadays its just light years ahead.